# Karaf how to exclude specified bundle from log

Tags: json, karaf

I would  like to exclude my bundle from root  karaf log. The JSON sended by this bundle is too large, and the log is no more readeable.

I suppose that I should change osgi:*  in line :

```
rootLogger=INFO,out,osgi:*
```

Which value I should put there ?

---

Edit, the problem is more complicated that I thought.

The JSON sont injected in logs by  org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-features-logging.  It is used also by other bundle. I vould like remove only JSON sending and receiving by my bundle.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude a specific bundle from logging, just turn off logging for the bundle within the pax logging config.

```
log4j.logger.mybundle = OFF
```

If you want to fine tune CXF message logging please check http://cxf.apache.org/docs/message-logging.html.

> Some things to note:
>
> The logger name is .. karaf by default only cuts it to just the type.
>       A lot of the details are in the MDC values
>       You need to change your pax logging config to make these visible.
>
> You can use the logger name to fine tune which services you want to log this way. For example set the debug level to WARN for noisy
>   services to avoid that they are logged or log some services to another
>   file.

Comment: This ling with apache CXF.. . I didn't see how it can help me ;( could you explain me it easly ?